# How to make Image blur in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

here is the example of nextjs

```
<Image
 blurDataURL="/poster.png"
 src={item.cover_path || defaultImage}
 alt={item.name}
 layout="fill"
 className="next-image"
 placeholder="[blur][1]"
/>
```

how can I make it easily in vuejs

someone help me if you have experience with vuejs, to make image's blur [image]

##### I found some useful resources "v-lazy-image"

```
<template>
  <div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="filter hidden">
      <defs>
        <filter id="blur">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" :stdDeviation="deviation" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
     <v-lazy-image
      :src="src"
      :src-placeholder="srcPlaceholder"
      @load="animate"
    ></v-lazy-image>
  </div>
</template>
```

here is Digital Ocean's tutorial [image-blur](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-progressive-image-rendering)

Answer (score 1):

The native Vue.js framework doesn't have such function. If you don't need to hide the source image very securely, just try to use the CSS attribute "filter: blur()".

According to: [MDN Web Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur).

Answer (score 0):

image-blur library requires an actual low-res image.

You might wanna check out [blurhash](https://blurha.sh/), which generates a hash string base on the original image, so you can display it while the original image is loading.